# What is the short story in ST:TNG about the Enterprise itself saving her crew?

Tags: story-identification, star-trek, star-trek-tng, uss-enterprise

1. I'm near positive it's in the [Strange New Worlds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Strange_New_Worlds) series
2. It was published between 2000 and 2010 IIRC
3. The story is from the perspective of the ***ship's computer***
4. Somehow the crew is incapacitated (IIRC Mr. Data as well) the ship performs the heroic rescue/saving of her crew *which no one will ever know*.
5. I don't recall this story winning any of the prizes, though it may have.

Can someone identify this story?

Comment: Whilst I know this is of a different era/series, it does sound slightly reminiscent of ST:Titan - Synthesis, there the ships computer is accidentally raised to Artificial Intelligence by a race of AI's, >! the ship later disobeys Captain Riker and sacrifices its own AI Matrix to stop the null

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having read through every summary available on [Memory Beta](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Strange_New_Worlds) of all the *TNG* stories in the 'Strange New Worlds' books, the closest I could find was'[**Of Cabbages and Kings**](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Of_Cabbages_and_Kings)' in *Strange New Worlds Vol I* (1998):

> The USS Enterprise is transported, without its crew, to an alternate universe, and has to develop its artificial intelligence to survive.

Not having read the story I can't provide much more information than that sorry, although it would be possible that this could fit the description.  That being said it is rather vague; my apologies!

Also bear in mind that several of the summaries were blank, so there are a couple of stories I wasn't able to make a judgement about.

Comment: Your name speaks for itself. Thx bud.